# Trigger to check values of two different tables

Tags: sql, triggers

I am trying to do a trigger in SQL that check the values on 2 different tables and compare if they are iqual, and then I can insert a value in another table.

I have the follow code:

```
create or replace TRIGGER "CHECK_COMMUNITY" 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Supply
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

SELECT [Client].*, [Office].* FROM Client INNER JOIN Office ON
[Client].[Community] = [Office].[Community]
WHERE 
[Supply].[id_client] = [Client].[id_client] 
AND [Suply].[id_office] = [Office].[id_office];

END;
```

I have 3 tables, and I want to check in Supply, after insert, if community of the tables Client and Office are equals.

I put it in SQl but I received the following error:

```
Error ORA-00936: missing expression
```

In

```
SELECT [Client].*, [Office].* FROM Client INNER JOIN Office ON
```

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't expect that error message when using SQL Server...

Comment: This is the original error:

Error(6,8): PL/SQL: ORA-00936: falta una expresión

Comment: That's an Oracle error message. But both the sql-server tag and your code indicates MS SQL Server - a completely different product when it comes to triggers.

Answer (score 0):

[Triggers](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_triggers.htm) are written to be executed in response to any of the following events:

A database manipulation (DML) statement (DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE).

A database definition (DDL) statement (CREATE, ALTER, or DROP).

A database operation (SERVERERROR, LOGON, LOGOFF, STARTUP, or SHUTDOWN).

And your Trigger body contains only a select statement which outputs result but does not know what to do with it.

Using :

```
create or replace TRIGGER "CHECK_COMMUNITY" 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Supply
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

Create table <table-name> as 
SELECT [Client].*, [Office].* FROM Client INNER JOIN Office ON
[Client].[Community] = [Office].[Community]
WHERE 
[Supply].[id_client] = [Client].[id_client] 
AND [Suply].[id_office] = [Office].[id_office];

END;
```

or

```
create or replace TRIGGER "CHECK_COMMUNITY" 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Supply
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
insert into table <table-name>
SELECT [Client].*, [Office].* FROM Client INNER JOIN Office ON
    [Client].[Community] = [Office].[Community]
    WHERE 
    [Supply].[id_client] = [Client].[id_client] 
    AND [Suply].[id_office] = [Office].[id_office];

    END;
```

Should work good

Comment: I have tried it but it continues with the same error. I don't want to create a new table, I have a table already to insert it.

Comment: No, it doesn't working. I have tried the code that you put but it doesn't work